# Get list of unique records using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 1000s of record in a table. Here is the table structure and records:-

Table_01

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Temp
(
    ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    Tech varchar(50)
    CONSTRAINT pk_table_01_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
GO
```

Insert records:-

```
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Temp] ([ID], [Name], [Tech]) VALUES (1, N'Apple', N'Kim')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Temp] ([ID], [Name], [Tech]) VALUES (2, N'Orange', N'Kim')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Temp] ([ID], [Name], [Tech]) VALUES (3, N'Pear', N'Paul')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Temp] ([ID], [Name], [Tech]) VALUES (4, N'Blueberry', N'Paul')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Temp] ([ID], [Name], [Tech]) VALUES (5, N'Blackberry', N'Paul')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table_Temp] ([ID], [Name], [Tech]) VALUES (6, N'Grapes', N'Sam')


ID  Name           Tech
1   Apple          Kim
2   Orange         Kim
3   Pear           Paul
4   Blueberry      Paul
5   Blackberry     Paul
6   Grapes         Sam
```

I need unique entries by Tech column and I need ID and Tech as my return values. Here is query I am using:-

```
SELECT distinct Tech, ID FROM Table_Temp
```

but result I am getting is not expected. Here is what I am expecting and unique records by Tech also returns ID,Tech together.

Result Expected:-

```
Kim, 1
Paul, 3
Sam, 6
```

Comment: Why negative? Whats wrong the question?

Comment: Thanks marc_s. but how will I get unique records as mentioned in question.

Comment: Oh.. Its unique by Tech column. but I also need that select query should also return ID of that row.

Comment: But why are you showing the `ID` 1 and 3 for Kim and Paul, but the `Name` Grapes for Sam ?!?!?!?!

Comment: It works fine when i just say distinct Tech. But i also need ID of all unique returns record. in other words I don't need uniqueness by ID or combination of Tech and ID

Comment: marc_s. updated by question..SAM, 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server **2005** or newer and you want to have **uniqueness by `Tech`** - then use something like this:

```
;WITH UniqueByTech AS
(
    SELECT
        Tech, Name, ID,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tech ORDER BY ID)
    FROM dbo.Table_Temp
)
SELECT Tech, ID
FROM UniqueByTech
WHERE RN = 1
```

<strike>But I'm still not understanding why you seem to be returning the `ID` for Kim and Paul but not for `Sam` - what's the logic ??</strike>

OK, with the update, now my CTE (Common Table Expression) shown here should give you what you're looking for.

The CTE basically "partitions" the data by whatever you want to have unique - here the `Tech` column - and then it numbers all rows in each partition starting from 1. If you want only 1 row per "partition", then just select the row with the `ROW_NUMBER()` equal to 1

Comment: Thats was typo. I need ID for Sam too

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear from your original posting what you are looking for, but based on the result set that you are expecting I believe that you need to modify your query as follows:

```
SELECT Tech, Min(ID)
FROM Table_Temp
GROUP BY Tech
```

(NOTE: I went with the assumption that "Grapes" returned for Sam was a typo, and that you actually intended to expect "6" as the value associated with Sam's entry.)